# Search the Number of occurrences of the particular words in data using Pandas.

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, nltk

I wanna Search how many times "bad"  and "good" words are repeated in the data frame and visualize  this with histogram.

Comment: How do you define 'bad' and 'good'? Got a dataset of examples of those? Please expand your question.

Comment: I just want to visualize how many times 'bad' word and 'good' word has repeated in particular column of  data frame.

Comment: If you want to specifically use `nltk` (since you have tagged nltk) there are many way to do this. For example tokenizing and getting word frequency. Give us a nice workable example, we can help you.

Comment: Visualise the positive and negative words distribution (Hint: Histogram)  
This is actual question for which i am searching the answer. I have the list of positive and negative words @i.n.n.m

Comment: @DhanshreeBagal So, you just need a histogram for your list? if so, just use `value_counts`.

Comment: from the above question I interpreted that in the Data frame I need to visualize how many positive and how many negative words are present. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Its always better to post a small workable sample data.Without knowing how your `df` and word frequency, I posted a general way to visualize data with histogram (Barplot).

Answer (score 1):

Jurgy's answer should work. However, based on comments above, you can simply do like this,

```
df['yourcolumn_name_good_bad'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

Otherwise, if you want to use `seaborn` library and create a plot follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460146/plotting-value-counts-in-seaborn-barplot).

Answer (score 0):

Without any knowledge how you would define 'good' or 'bad' this would be the general approach:

```
def count_good(text):
    # TODO: how do you define good?
    pass


def count_bad(text):
    # TODO: how do you define bad?
    pass

def analyze(df)
    good_count = df.words.apply(count_good).sum()
    bad_count = df.words.apply(count_bad).sum()

    plt.bar([0, 1], [good_count, bad_count])
    plt.xticks([0, 1], ['Good', 'Bad'])
    plt.show()
```

But you really need to improve your question if you want a serious answer.